# Can I assign new values without erasing array in VBA VB6?

Tags: arrays, vb6

Hi I assign values to an array from an ADO record set.  A bit later I could reassign values to the array, ... **will the new values overwrite the old ones or add to them? Do I need to erase array first?** I would prefer not to erase because a few times I've had an empty array and it pulls up an error when trying to erase. Simply eliminating the erase step would help greatly.

```
ReturnArray = myRecSet.GetRows
```

Comment: If you use the `=` operator, it will overwrite the array. Just like how it would do with any other variable.

Comment: Is It VBA or VB6. the two are really close but not exactly the same.

Comment: It's VB6 actually.  and yes, I thought it would work like a variable but I wasn't sure so I thought I would ask.